# Python Sockets Password Input

Tags: python, sockets

I am creating a basic login page using Python Sockets and I am trying to make the Password input blank when the user types, I am using CLIENT.send() to send the "Password: " string and CLIENT.recv(1024) to fetch the given data.

Comment: But what is the client doing?

If they're using a terminal emulator, and you know the emulation (vt100, etc.), you might be able to send terminal commands to turn echo off.

Comment: The client is connecting through a telnet connection using Putty.

Comment: Sounds like you should experiment with escape sequences (google vt100 escape sequences or similar).  Normally a library like ncurses would take care of this.  You also have to make sure the client is using a compatible emulation.  Since you're not implementing full telnet, you won't know what terminal emulation they're using.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the getpass library like this:

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass()
```

this will make the password variable get an input, but nothing will come up as you type

Comment: NOTE: this doesnt work if you run it in the python IDLE